# Get image of android OS without rooting the device

Tags: device-firmware

As part of my academic project, I want to get the image of a whole Android OS of a non-rooted device in order to do forensics activity.

Can I do this using SCSI commands as SCSI directly communicates with hardware and does not need root permission?

I got information that SCSI interaction is possible with Android non-rooted device from 
[Implementation of an Android Framework
for USB storage access without root rights](https://www.os.in.tum.de/fileadmin/w00bdp/www/Lehre/Abschlussarbeiten/Jahnen-thesis.pdf)

Comment: Similar question: [Android device information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074584/android-device-information) Ref: [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) & [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)  You haven't told from, where you need to access the data. (development is offtopic here)_  [Asking](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I want to access the complete ROM of android device without rooting it, Searching if there is any way to do that.

Comment: There are different ROM's(stock & custom) available for different devices. Could you please edit your question and add the device information and Android version. Look for this related post [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)